# get current address of user in xcode?

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I need to get the exact current address (country,state,city) of user. So I have gone to find latitude and longitude and then find out from it by using reverse geocoding.But unable to get latitude and longitude itself.I m using xcode 4.1  and testing in iphone simulator.

This is the code I m working on:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; 
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self deviceLocation]);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
    int minutes = decimal * 60;
    double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                     degrees, minutes, seconds];
    latLabel.text = lat;
    degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
    minutes = decimal * 60;
    seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    NSString *longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                       degrees, minutes, seconds];
    longLabel.text = longt;
}
```

How can I find the latitude and longitude and thereby find the address of the user?

EDIT:

Updated my version to Xcode 4.5. But still couldnot see the location ....?Y is it so?

Comment: Xcode doesn't really have anything to do with the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please download [this file](http://www.sendspace.com/file/6quoja)

In the zip file I attached, there are 4 files:

**LocationGetter.h and .m**

**PhysicalLocation.h and .m**

you need to just import

`#import "PhysicalLocation.h"`

```
 PhysicalLocation *physicalLocation = [[PhysicalLocation alloc] init];
    [physicalLocation getPhysicalLocation];
```

in `getPhysicalLocation` at `PhysicalLocation.m` class

```
#pragma mark MKReverseGeocoder Delegate Methods
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{

    NSLog(@"%@",placemark);

    objcntrAppDelegate = (yourappDeleger *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    objcntrAppDelegate.strCountry=placemark.country;
    objcntrAppDelegate.strSuburb=placemark.subAdministrativeArea;


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReceivedAddress" object:nil userInfo:nil];


     [geocoder autorelease];
}
```

You get all of you neat lat, lng, current city, country, all that you need. Hope it helps you.
**NOTE:-** simulator gives incorrect result, you must test on device.

**UPDATE**

[UpdatedDEMO](http://www.sendspace.com/file/eu7bzm)

Comment: but i found that MKReverseGeocoder is depracated in ios5..can i use it still?

Comment: i can use this one and got result in ios6 or ios5 its working for me thatch why i just post this methods for you

Comment: my mate working as same conflagration and its get result as well

Comment: k i have downloaded the zip files.now should i attach all of them in my project?

Comment: yes its 4 file add in you project drag n drop and check copy option then in your app delegate you just import file as mantion my answer and do following as my post

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19671/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-arizah)

Comment: Hey nitin .I m back.I have upgraded my version of xcode and getting location default as sanfransisco.But I have some doubts and need ur clarification ..I would be grateful to u ..

Comment: How can I get the state from it ?bcoz in the default address it is showing SanFransisco is city and UnitedStates is a country .I need to get the state...

Comment: Thanks to u for helping me ..nd if im not wrong we get state using administrative area right ?

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
```

Now latitude and longitude should be obtained as `float` not `int`.

```
CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
// Configure the new event with information from the location
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

float longitude=coordinate.longitude;
float latitude=coordinate.latitude;
```

Find address of the user by latitude and longitude using `CLGeocoder`.

**EDIT** : Refer [this](http://jonathanfield.me/jons-blog/clgeocoder-example.html) link.